# AKS, can't deploy a model, error whire reading a csv file

Tags: python, pandas, algorithm, csv, kubernetes-pod

I am trying to deploy an algorithm on AKS, and I have a problem which I am blocking.

The algo creates 2 files csv which will be useful to train the machine learning model,the problem occurs when in the script, the file must be read, I have this error:

[image: Error pandas read]

**TypeError: ufunc 'isnan' not supported for the input types, and the inputs could not be safely coerced to any supported types according to the casting rule ''safe''.**

That I do not understand not .. this same file before reading it in script, I upload it to a storage account on Azure, to test, I download it, and i can read it without problem locally, with the same line of pandas read, I did not modify anything.

Here are the libraries and their respective versions of my requirements file:

scikit-learn 0.22.2
numpy 1.17.2
pandas 0.25.1
azure-storage-blob12.5.0
python 3.7.4

I imagine it's a config problem on AKS, a technology I've never used before, but I can't understand where it gets stuck given that locally with these same libraries it works.

Thank you for your answers

EDIT:
It may not be clear, so I'm trying to be more specific :
What I am trying to do is simply read the csv file.
The error occur when the read_csv pandas Function call the isnan numpy function.

**filecsv = pd.read_csv('path/file.csv', index_col='Id_arc', sep=';', encoding="utf8", error_bad_lines=False, low_memory=False)**

It seem that a parameter cannot be interpreted by the isnan Function, which is strange because it does work verry well in local.
The isnan Function is located in the core library of pandas.

Comment: not enough info here to figure out anything. what is the function doing? where is input coming from? how are you  deploying on aks? ...

Comment: The file I'm trying to read is generated in a previous function, there is just a join with 2 input csv file to generate it.

In the function where I try to read it, it is the first line, there is a whole processing on the data after.

The deployment is done with a yaml file on a kubernetes cluster on aks.

Comment: What I am trying to do is simply read the csv file.
The error occur when the read_csv pandas Function call the isnan numpy function.


filecsv = pd.read_csv('path/file.csv', index_col='Id_arc', sep=';', encoding="utf8", error_bad_lines=False, low_memory=False)

It seem that a parameter cannot be interpreted by the isnan Function, which is strange because it does work verry well in local.
The isnan Function is located in the core library of pandas.